# How can I pre-select Ag-Grid rows from React state?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

When rows are selected by the user, I save which rows are selected in some state. When the grid is rendered, I want those rows to still be selected. I've tried in `onModelChanged` calling `setSelected` on all the selected rows. However, this is not performant when lots of rows are selected. Also, there is a visible moment before the rows are selected, which is not ideal.

Is there any way I can pre-select rows *before* the grid is rendered?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to select a row by using `firstDataRendered` event.

```js
gridAPI.addEventListener(
  "firstDataRendered",
  ({ api }) => {
    // Has to wait until the next tick
    setTimeout(() => {
      api.getDisplayedRowAtIndex(0).selectThisNode(true);
    }, 0);
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can preselect rows like below example.

```
onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode(node=> node.rowIndex === 1 ? node.setSelected (true) : node.setSelected(false));
}
```

You can make condition based on your state.

Comment: thanks for this, but I'm am nearly positive that the rows have not been loaded into the grid in `onGridReady` so `forEachNode` is called on an empty list. I'll have to double check, but I'm pretty sure I tried this.

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes but it can be achieve by making rowData check in ag grid component means load component once rowData ready. I tried this and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can pre-select rows before the grid is rendered?

I assume that you are looking for configuration like `editable` for columns (its configurable), `columns` exist after `gridReady` event, but `rows` - only after `firstRenderer` event.

On top of that there are no properties for rows and as far as I know (and also double-checked on doc) there is no `settings` for that.

I mean you can configure lots of things, but the selection is out of it.

And on their examples, [they are using](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/#example-using-foreachnode) `forEach` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firstDataRendered. Then loop on each node to set the data as selected. Hope this helps you!

[image: firstDataRendered]